# Specific pod Cpu usage in Prometheus

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have deployed prometheus on top Kubernetes.
My requirement is to get CPU utilization of a Specific Pod. Although i am currently using this, i dont think its giving out correct values, as there is absolutely no load on the cluster, still pod cpu utilization is very high.

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod_name=~"tiller-deploy.*", image=~"gcr.io/kubernetes-.*"}[2m]))  /  sum(machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_hostname="ip-172-21-58-79.us-east-2.compute.internal"})  * 100
```

[image]